# RegExp.test not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate year using Regex.test in javascript, but no able to figure out why its returning false.

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(19|20)[\d]{2,2}$");
```

`regEx.test(inputValue)` returns false for input value 1981, 2007

Thanks

Comment: Uh, do you mean "1981, 2007" or "1981" and "2007"?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As you're creating a `RegExp` object using a string expression, you need to double the backslashes so they escape properly. Also `[\d]{2,2}` can be simplified to `\d\d`:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("^(19|20)\\d\\d$");
```

Or better yet use a regex literal to avoid doubling backslashes:

```
var regEx = /^(19|20)\d\d$/;
```

Comment: you save me! man. god, bless you. what is the reason of /[0-9]*/.test("L") return true? in ionic or javascript or ...

Comment: @Mote Zart: The single backslash means nothing in a string if it isn't escaped so you're just testing for the literal string `w+`. That's why it needs to be doubled.

Answer (score 11):

Found the **REAL** issue:

Change your declaration to remove quotes:

```
var regEx = new RegExp(/^(19|20)[\d]{2,2}$/);
```

Comment: You may as well just use the regex literal rather than passing it to *another* `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: True. Although it was interesting to figure out the issue with the original ask.

Comment: (head banging)This is the correct answer- the single quotes encapsulating the reg expression. I have up-voted all involved as all helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean

```
var inputValue = "1981, 2007";
```

If so, this will fail because the pattern is not matched due to the start string (^) and end string ($) characters.

If you want to capture both years, remove these characters from your pattern and do a global match (with /g)

```
var regEx = new RegExp(/(?:19|20)\d{2}/g);
var inputValue = "1981, 2007";
var matches = inputValue.match(regEx);
```

matches will be an array containing all matches.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed, for reasons I can't explain, sometimes you have to have two \\ in front of the d.

so try [\\d] and see if that helps.